# How can I insert the combos with texts in the same row of Kendo Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Would like to know, how can I insert the combos of first line of columns 'Tipo de Atendimento' and 'Motivo' with the texts of columns 'usuário' and 'Hora Final' in the same row? It's possible?

See the example: http://dojo.telerik.com/OMePo/6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I thinked the other way.

See the result: http://dojo.telerik.com/OMePo/10